# picture do not show in sails.js view

Tags: sails.js

My assets folder :

```
assets  
     | images  
            | media  
                  | book  
                        | pictures
```

i want to create new book when i upload book picture in above path, But when i try to show this image in view, the image can not be displayed and there is no error either.
my code is:

```
//BookController
create: function (request, response, next) {
var title = request.body.title;
var subject = request.body.subject;
var brief = request.body.brief;
var author = request.body.author;
var origin_pic_name = null;

request.file('pic').upload({
  dirname: '../../assets/images/media/book/pictures/',
},function (err, file) {
  if(err) console.log(err);
  origin_pic_name = file[0]['fd'].split('\\').reverse()[0] ;

  Book.create({title:title,subject:subject,brief:brief,author:author,pic:origin_pic_name}).exec(function (err) {
    if(err) response.end(500, {error: 'Database Error'});
    response.redirect('/');
  });

});},  

index : function (request, response, next) {
Book.find({}).exec(function (err, books) {
  if(err) response.end(500, {error: 'Database Error'});
  response.view('book/index', {books:books});
});},  

//my index.ejs
<ol>
<% books.forEach(function (value) {%>
  <h3><li> <%= value.title %></li></h3>
  <ul><%= value.author %></ul>
  <ul><%= value.subject %></ul>
  <ul><%= value.brief %></ul>
  <ul><img src="/images/media/book/pictures/<%= value.pic %>"/></ul>
<% })%>
</ol>
```

thank you

Comment: Does the filename the image is saved under match the filename stored in the database?

Comment: @Glen, Yes, the file name with the name stored in the database is one.              i do not know what my problem is?
I searched a lot on the internet but did not get the answer!

Comment: Most likely the images are not been stored in the .tmp directory so are not available until the app is restarted. You can resolve that by saving the image on upload to both the .tmp and main assets folder or by running a script that monitors and copies from the main assets folder to .tmp folder when a new file is uploaded.

Comment: tank you, Yes you are rightو Do you have any other solution to this problem?I think that Flexibility sails to Working with assets is not good.

Comment: Let me pop in a answer with some code for you.

Comment: Thanks really, so I'm waiting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be very careful when uploading images to Sails:

## The Problem

Grunt is watching for changes in some folders, including the `assets` dir and subdirs. But that is only possible (activacted, tbh) in "Development" enviroment.

## The solution

- Create a `images/` dir in your root.
- When uploading the image, make `skipper` save the image there.
- Write a `mediaController` that will catch routes like `/images/media/book/:name` and will try to locate and send a file:

  ```
  // MediaController.js
  var fs = require('fs');
  var path = require('path');

  module.exports = {
      get : function(req, res){
          var filepath = req.name.slice(1,req.name.length);

          // remove this Sync to an Async 
          if(fs.existsSync(path.resolve(filepath))){
              return res.sendfile(filepath);
          } else {
              return res.notFound();  
          }
      }
  }

  //Routes.js
  'get /images/books/:name' : 'MediaController.get'
  ```

### Advantages

- You can now restrict the access of images with policies, if you want to!
- Better handling at image and 100% control over the `fs`. Good with `DO Spaces`, for example...

Comment: Credit to @arbuthnott that helped last year to solve this exactly problem.

Comment: This method is good and the result is correct.
But some parts of the code should be changed:
1 - req.param('name').slice(0,req.param('name').length)
2 - path.resolve('images\\'+filepath) // We must also place the path where the photos are stored.in this case is 'images'. Thanks really

Answer (score 2):

Out of the box, sails caches assets during the sails lift process. To get around this, for file uploads, you can alter your controller to copy the file immediately after upload.

Here is an example of how you might do that with your current controller. You may need to edit the directory strings to suit your needs.

```
// BookController
create: function (request, response, next) {
    var title = request.body.title;
    var subject = request.body.subject;
    var brief = request.body.brief;
    var author = request.body.author;
    var origin_pic_name = null;

    request.file('pic').upload({
        dirname: '../../assets/images/media/book/pictures/',
    },function (err, file) {
        if(err) console.log(err);

        origin_pic_name = file[0]['fd'].split('\\').reverse()[0];

        // Variable to hold the current directory
        var currentDir = '../../assets/images/media/book/pictures/' + origin_pic_name;

        // Variable to hold the temp directory
        var tempDir = '.tmp/public/images/media/book/pictures/' + origin_pic_name;

        // copy the image from the current directory to the temp to the temp folder
        fs.createReadStream(currentDir).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(tempDir));

        Book.create({title:title,subject:subject,brief:brief,author:author,pic:origin_pic_name}).exec(function (err) {
            if(err) response.end(500, {error: 'Database Error'});
            response.redirect('/');
        });
    });
},
```

Comment: Your solution is also very good.
But I think @paulogdm solution is better and more comprehensive
In any case, thank you for the time you spent on this problem

Comment: It certainly is, it was the alternative option I was going to give ya but @paulogdm pipped me to the post, so I just threw this up as an alternative. :)