# Images are uploaded but not visible in UI => sails js

Tags: node.js, sails.js

Images are got uploaded in the assets folder but it's not visible in the UI. When I restart the server then I could see the image.

**Problem:** Images are only getting stored in the assets but has not stored in the `.tmp` file.

When restarting server the `.tmp` reads all the files which are in the assets folder, but it is not happening while uploading image.

This is the situation which I am facing.

This is the code i tried to solve it with:

```
var file = req.file('logo'); 
file.upload({ dirname: '../../assets/images' }, function onUploadComplete (err, files) { 
    if (err) { 
        console.log("something went wrong") ;
    } else { 
        console.log("File has uploaded successfully");
    }
});
```

Comment: var file = req.file('logo');
  file.upload({
     dirname: '../../assets/images'
   }, function onUploadComplete(err, files) {
      if(err){
        console.log("something went wrong")
      }else{
         console.log("File has uploaded successfully")
       }
   })

 Once file has got uploaded, I try to read the location of the file in browser as follows

 localhost:1337/images/fileName.png

 but it's not showing the image.

 when I restart the project, then it's showing the image.

Comment: Please edit the code and explanation into the question itself

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48670991/picture-do-not-show-in-sails-js-view/48686250?noredirect=1#comment84378181_48686250

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are seeing the file after the server is restarted is because of the grunt task copying the assets into the .tmp folder. So there are a few things you may want to do to fix your issue:

1. Copy the file to the .tmp folder yourself in the onUploadComplete callback.
2. Set the grunt to monitor for changes, but I think this is not a good practice for production.
3. On upload move your file from the server to some other repository service (I use S3 service of AWS for example). By the way, I think this is the best choice since you decouple your static assets from uploaded content - if you ever need to redeploy the server, you may loose the uploaded images.
4. You can always save images as a base64 encoded strings in a DB, so no issues with paths, file system operations, etc., but then you are putting a lot of load on your DB.

Comment: When I run code via "sails lift" the application itself doing the process of coping the images from assets to .tmp folder. But it's not happening when I run the command "forever start app.js".                                                                   I don't know why the grunt task is not coping the file when I run the command "forever start app.js"